# 2sxc Manage Content/Data for non host

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

Is possible to use "Mange Content / Data" for single entity for specific user or group.

I create app with multiple Content data, but now I would like to enable some users
to be able to display and edit list of entities like in Administration.

But don't want that user can mess with all application data and settings.

I want to use the view from admin because it has nice filtering and sorting capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to give them an edit-table, then just create a view which shows all items and provides an edit button. then put that on a special page just for these users.

Comment: I ask how to show view like in admin, because of all soring and filtering from this admin view.

Comment: For the admin view there is no quick solution - sorry :(